# Compiler issue or some bug in code block of c

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

The very amazing and shocking logical problem occur which simple coding in **c++**.

> See the following two chunk of code.

*code 1*

```
int m = 5, n = 0;
n = m++ * ++m;
//This print m = 7 and n = 36
//Which is logically wrong
```

*code 2*

```
int m = 5;
int n = m++ * ++m;
//This print m = 7 and n = 35
//Which is logically right
```

As we think logically the code block 2 gives right answer, but the amazing or magic thing is that what is wrong with code block1?

As part code its same, just we declared `int n` earlier.

May be some compile!!!!!!

Comment: `m++ * ++m` is *undefined behaviour*. There is nothing "logically wrong" about your output; it's your code that's broken.

Comment: I guess a valid question is: why is this compiler implementation working this way.

Comment: @RaymondChen, you did not answer my question. The implementation could have spawned a Tic-Tac-Toe game, but it didn't.

Comment: Don't think this question deserved downvotes - maybe marked / closed as a duplicate wrt sequence points and undefined behaviour. This stuff can be surprising to a novice (and new member) who wants some clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order especially the part which discusses "Undefined behavior".  Basically it's not a bug in the compiler.  The language says what you're doing is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the "undefined behavior" part, which is important, there's nothing illogical here. Assuming the evaluation is from right to left:

```
++m -> value is 6, m is 6
m++ -> value is 6, m is 7
6*6 = 36
```